Display answers I've upvoted first
I always upvote Q/A's to serve as a breadcrumb to myself. If I see an upvoted Q/A, I know I encountered that problem before and found the Q/A helpful.
With that in mind, it would be nice to have a sort order which always shows my personally upvoted answers first.

I'm sure this is a dupe of something but I can't seem to find it

I requested something like this on MSE earlier this year: Add an option to sort answers by the viewer's previously cast votes.
